# Defining the character encoding of a JavaScript source file

Tags: javascript, unicode, encoding

I would like to print a status message to my German users, which contains umlauts (ä/ü/ö). I also would like them be in the source file rather than having to download and parse some extra file just for the messages.

However, I can't seem to find a way to define the encoding of a JS source file. Is there something like HTML's `http-equiv`? Or should I define the encoding in the HTTP header?

When I simply encode the file in UTF-8 an serve it, IE displays garbage.

Comment: You should go with the HTTP header.

Comment: Tomcat-only for local development. Static files are served by Apache on the production system.

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833231/how-to-declare-character-encoding-in-an-individual-js-file

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sending the encoding in the headers is always a good idea.

If that's not possible, the `<script>` tag has the `charset` property. [**W3C Reference**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

```
<script src="translations.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

It seems that the charset attribute for the script tag is not deprecated in HTML5 (it is deprecated only for a and link tags).

Answer (score 4):

This might sound a bit dumb, but make sure you save your javascript file with the correct encoding in the editor you are using. I had a problem with the encoding of my javascript file, and the solution was as simple as this!

Answer (score 3):

While the charset parameter would seem helpful, it's important to note that it's actually deprecated in HTML5.

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations#charset

Comment: So what's the alternative then?

Comment: The alternative is to define the charset in the HTTP headers.

Comment: @MicahHenning And what if you can't define it in the HTTP headers?

Comment: Ultimately, it's the web server that defines the character set of the code being sent to the web browser, no matter if you use the `charset` parameter.

Comment: Or what if you aren't using a web server and running HTML files locally?

Comment: HTML5 does not deprecated the property `charset` on a script tag.  The link above only deals with links and not script.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-charset

Comment: @VernBurton Yes, you are correct.  Perhaps in June of 2012 when I made this post my understanding was that the `charset` parameter was deprecated, but then it was later re-added.  After all, HTML 5 wasn't finalized until late 2014.

Answer (score 2):

For french javascript js, we've used another charset :

```
<script src="./js/MyScript.js" type="text/javascript" charset="iso-8859-1"></script>
```

Comment: you should use utf-8, this charset will allow iso-8859-1 characters and more.

Comment: unless of course you explicitly desire to support *no more* than good ole French ;)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution to your problem would be to use unicode escape for special character in strings. This way, your code is not affected by the page that's hosting it.

A tool that might help you: http://www.webstein.net/tools/javascript-unicode

Comment: Link is unfortunately dead.