# Is there a way to declare a JavaScript file’s encoding within the file itself, like CSS’s @charset rule?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

In CSS, you can declare the text encoding of the CSS file using the `@charset` at-rule at the very top of the file. For example:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
```

(See http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset.en.php).

Is there a similar mechanism for JavaScript files? (Aside from the `Content-Type` HTTP header.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare character encoding in an INDIVIDUAL JS file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833231/how-to-declare-character-encoding-in-an-individual-js-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of this being closed as a duplicate: no, there’s not.

See [How to declare character encoding in an INDIVIDUAL JS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833231/how-to-declare-character-encoding-in-an-individual-js-file)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- I normally use this meta tag -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- ... -->
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="path/to/your/file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good to know, but I did say “within the file itself”.

Comment: So maybe this solve your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833231/how-to-declare-character-encoding-in-an-individual-js-file